# why goddady changes the url on response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I have a subfolder in the web site (ASP.Net) named "wcms" which contains several files including "login.aspx" and "index.aspx". the login page checks the username and password and redirect the page to the index.aspx.

This works fine when I run it locally on the development machine, but when I call the login:
https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/sitepreview/http/hebron-city.ps/wcms/login.aspx
it cuts out some of the path and redirects me to:
https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/wcms/index.aspx

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your first link is looking like a preview may be godaddy is reidrecting it to the Correct Location

Comment: I opened the site from the preview link in godaddy, other links from the httpdoc folder work fine, and when I type /wcms/login.aspx, it works, but when it redirects me using:
"Response.Redirect("index.aspx", False)" it redirects me to the wrong URL

Comment: try redirecting like 'Response.Redirect("~/wcms/index.aspx",false);'

Comment: Same result :(, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not Depend on the preview links in all your Redirects try using full path from the root Folder like here your root path including domain name  is `https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/` so Redirect all your links like

```
Response.Redirect("~/wcms/index.aspx");
Response.Redirect("~/wcms/login.aspx");
```

This will remove the ambiguity of Wrong redirection.

and call your login page from url

```
https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/wcms/login.aspx
```

not from

```
https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/sitepreview/http/hebron-city.ps/wcms/login.aspx
```

Comment: https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/wcms/login.aspx
leads to a 404 error

Comment: There is some configuration issue as when i try to open this url 'https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/sitepreview/http/hebron-city.ps/wcms/index.aspx' it is redirecting me to 'https://p3nwvpweb123.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:8443/wcms/login.aspx' and giving 404. Try Contacting godaddy tech Support Guys